# C# find common elements in list of lists

Tags: c#

How can I efficiently get the common element in each list of a list in C#
Like:
result = { {"a","b","c"}, {"c","b","e","r"}, {"c","b"}}
It should give a list {"b","c"}
so far I have

```
var common = result[0].Intersect(result[1])
foreach(l in result[2..^0]
{
   common = common.Intersect(l);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `.Intersect()`? I do not understand what is going on in your code snippet///

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `Intersect` multiple times, which will (I suspect) create a new `HashSet` each time internally, I'd use:

```cs
var set = result[0].ToHashSet();
foreach (var sublist in result.Skip(1))
{
    set.IntersectWith(sublist);
}
```